# How to properly make custom templates which are images in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I was assigned a very obscure project where basically every control, every design element is an image. I was provided with design files for every element of the app.

I even informed the people who gave the assignment that it's probably a very bad idea due to many different reasons, and it would be better to do everything manually but I still have to do it with images. Every time I add something - I see that everything is fine in the designer , but when I run it on my **Lumia 925** everything shifts a little bit in different directions, even the buttons.

Any suggestions on the proper way to do this? To have custom templates for buttons which are basically images in a way it will not shift and I would see the same thing in the designer and on the device.

Comment: Hello please post the code where you are seeing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a great solution for controls called Behaviors, just add the extension in the project and add the following everywhere you need a Tap like the following, (that's an example just for tap you could use the event tap):
 xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" 
 xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"

```
 <Image> 
 <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
   <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
     <core:CallMethodAction .../>
   </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
  ...
 </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

You have all the behaviors and actions here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xaml.interactions.core.aspx

and how to add them in the project here:

http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/07/22/tips-and-tricks-for-using-xaml-controls-in-your-universal-windows-apps/

Then add the logic in the methods you call from the images. There are plenty of behaviors done, to begin storyboards, to change properties...

Apart you can use a ViewBox control that it scales everything in the screen to not be scaling every image. Try that.